# Amazon Amplify Deployment fail - for Next Js app

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to deploy a NextJs app in Amplify. but build is failing

Below is the build log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmsck.png)

Comment: Try updating the Node.js version used in AWS Amplify. Next.js 12 requires Node >=12.22.0.

Comment: Please add error messages as text to your question and not as image. Besides that the error message clearly states that the Node version you use is too small. Use a Node version >= 12.22.0